# How to handle a request with node/express that requires two asynchronous methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm learning node. I have a web application that is interfacing with bitcoind through the [bitcoin](https://npmjs.org/package/bitcoin) package, and PostgreSQL through [knex](https://npmjs.org/package/knex). I need to get a bit of data from each module and then pass it all to my view for rendering. My code looks like this so far:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  var testnet='';
  bitcoin.getInfo(function(e, info){
    if(e){ return console.log(e);}
    if(info.testnet){
      testnet='bitcoin RPC is testnet';
    }else{
      testnet='nope.. you must be crazy';
    }
    var c=knex('config').select().then(function(k){
      res.render('index', { title: k[0].site_name, testnet: testnet });
    });
  });
};
```

The way this is structured though, it will first wait for Bitcoin to reply, and then it will  issue the request to PostgreSQL, and then wait a while longer for it to reply. These two wait periods could clearly happen simultaneously. However, I don't know how to do that with promises/callbacks in Javascript. How can I manage this to happen asynchronously, rather than serially?

Comment: does your request to Postgre rely on the response from Bitcoin?

Comment: @r3mus not always. Sometimes it can be in parallel

Comment: If not, then Joe's answer is definitely the way to go. If ever it does reply on the response, then you won't be able to run those async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to promisify callback methods, not mix callbacks and promises.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var bitcoin = require("bitcoin");
//Now the bitcoin client has promise methods with *Async postfix
Promise.promisifyAll(bitcoin.Client.prototype);

var client = new bitcoin.Client({...});
```

Then the actual code:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    var info = client.getInfoAsync();
    var config = knex('config').select();

    Promise.all([info, config]).spread(function(info, config) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: config[0].site_name,
            testnet: info.testnet ? 'bitcoin RPC is testnet' : 'nope.. you must be crazy'
        });
    }).catch(function(e){
        //This will catch **both** info and config errors, which your code didn't
        //do
        console.log(e);
    });
};
```

Promise module [bluebird](https://npmjs.org/package/bluebird) is used.

Comment: That is very interesting. I didn't know about Promisify, or how elegant the code could be when it was all promises

Comment: @Earlz yep, having the results as values in normal variables is really awesome

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module which will let you fire off both tasks then continue on.

An untested example to give you the idea:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var testnet='', k={};

    async.parallel([
      function(){ 
        bitcoin.getInfo(function(e, info){
          //your getInfo callback logic
           },
      function(){
        knex('config').select().then(function(result) {       
         //your knex callback
         k = result;
      } ],
      //Here's the final callback when both are complete
      function() {
         res.render('index', { title: k[0].site_name, testnet: testnet });
      });
}
```

Comment: The actual code that would make this work is significantly more complicated, especially with error handling :/

Comment: btw, for future reference, this is the relevant commit I made to my code. Notable is that each parallel task must take and call a callback function to indicate it's done. https://github.com/Earlz/d4btc/commit/9f20fcee94148744139a0f5ecb428ca439bc826f

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a library like [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async)'s `#parallel()` method or you could poke around its source and learn to role your own